# how incriment 000000 in python?

Tags: python, numbers, range

I wrote python script where im connecing to api, entering number and get responce from it

```
import requests
import re
while True:
   number1 = input("nomeri ")
   num = "number"
   params = {}
   params[num]= number1
   var = requests.post('api', data = params)
   info = str(var.text)

   m = re.search('"info":{"name":\"(.+?)\"}}', info)
  if m:
    found = m.group(1)
    var = u"{}".format(found)
    text = open("text.txt", 'a')
    text.write(number1)
    print(var )
   else:
    print("not found")
```

now i want to reorginize it, and check number range from 000000 to 999999 and if it found write it to text file.range will be 0000009, 000090,000091 etc, how can i generate it?

Comment: `requests` will parse the JSON for you, if you access `var.json()`; don't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the string `format`ting itself :)

```
for i in range(999999+1):  # if python3, use xrange :)
    print("{:07}".format(i))
```

Comment: tried its working but it printing 7 digit how can i print 6 digit?

Comment: one queston how can i start loop for example after 170?

Comment: `for i in range(170, 999999+1):..print(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Strings have a handy `zfill()` method to pad the left of a string with zeroes. So just keep track of it as an integer (or convert it to an integer if it's a string), increment it as usual, convert it to a string, and apply zfill.

```
num = 1
while True:
    print(str(num).zfill(7))
    num += 1
```